# MATLAB-style replacement of array values that meet certain condition in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

For a given array **A** suppose we need to replace all its elements satisfying a certain condition by some value (say elements greater than 10 by 10). In Matlab one can do this in a single line by

```
A[A>10] = 10
```

The above command does not work in Julia (v >= 1.0).

I understand that, except the brute force solution of looping over the array, one can use **maps** and the above in **Julia** can be accomplished by

```
A = map( x -> if (x > 10 ) 10 else x end , A);
```

which is still a 1 line solution.

Given that this type of array replacements are ubiquitous,  I'm wondering if there is a Julia equivalent of the MATLAB command mentioned above, which is just too neat.

Comment: I know this is a dupe but I can't find it at the moment.  Julia's just stricter these days about when she broadcasts: you can use `A[A .> 10] .= 10` to get the behaviour you want.  (Still looking for the dupe..)

Comment: (I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573369/how-do-you-perform-conditional-assignment-in-arrays-in-julia) might be close enough to use as a target, but I'll let others judge.)

Comment: @DSM, thanks! The dot did the job. As for the link you have in your second comment, I see now that my question is about the same feature of Julia, although somehow my google search did not get me there. So, if you'll make your initial comment as an answer, I'd accept it. I trust it would be useful for others too.

Comment: @DSM Same answer and similar example in question. Close enough for me. I've opened a close vote.

Comment: In Julia v1.0 there is a new, and considerably faster option than `A[A .> 10] .= 10`, which needlessly allocates a temporary array. Use the `replace!` function instead, like this: `replace!(x -> x>10 ? 10 : x, A)`. In my tests, it gives a > 10x speedup.

Comment: Also, this one is quite nice: `A .= min.(A, 10)`.

Comment: @DNF, thanks for the suggestions! both worked nicely.